# Does standard C really specify that a pointer to an object should contain the lowest address of all the bytes the object consists of?

Tags: c, pointers, memory-address

I searched C standard for that, but I didn't find anything about that question. If that's implementation-defined, why is it always safe to use **malloc** like this?

```
char *p = (char*) malloc(100);
if (p == NULL)
      return;

for (i=0; i<100; i++)
{
     p[i] = ........
}
```

Comment: You meaning checking for the returned value of NULL?

Comment: Are you asking whether it's well-defined that `malloc` returns a pointer to the *start* of the allocated memory?

Comment: FWIW, 6.3.2.3 p7 states "*When a pointer to an object is converted to a pointer to a character type, the result points to the lowest addressed byte of the object."*

Comment: From the C11 standard (7.22.3 on malloc): "The pointer returned points to the start (lowest byte address) of the allocated space". Duh. And the entire standard and C memory model would be incoherent if a pointer to an object pointed into the middle of the object.

Answer (score 1):

malloc returns NULL if it couldn't allocate the memory.  That's why you can test like that.

NULL is defined in the standard as a null pointer, and is guaranteed to compare unequal
to a pointer to any object or function.  It's an address for something that can never be a memory location.

A pointer just points at a memory location.  In C, when you allocate memory, the first byte of that memory is always what's going to be pointed to. Knowing where the memory starts, and the size, you can know where it ends.

But a pointer can point to anywhere in that array.  You can set a char * p_pointer = p + 1 or the equivalent &p[1];  p_pointer[-1] points to p[0].